# how to print the contents of the vector to screen in c++ whose each element is pair in a pair

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I am working on a assignment in which the elements of the vector of this type `vector<pair<string,pair<int,int> > > A` .

```
for(auto it=A.begin();it!=A.end();it++) 
    cout <<*it.first<<" "<< *it.second.first <<" "<<*it.second.second;
```

but it is showing errors.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What errors do you get?  Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: `*it.first` should be `(*it).first` or `it->first`, same for the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `(*it).first` instead of `*it.first`, because `*it.first` means a iterator which is `it.first`, but actually the iterator is `(*it)`.

You can get rid of this problem by using `->`, like `it->first`. Because if you use `->` it is lot easier than using `*`.

```
vector<pair<string,pair<int,int> > > A;

for(auto it = A.begin(); it != A.end(); it++){
    //cout << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second.first << " " << (*it).second.second; 
    cout << it->first << " " << it->second->first << " " << it->second->second;
}
```

Comment: when you say "pointer" do you mean "iterator" ? vectors iterators can be pointers but thats an implementation detail

Answer (score 3):

This is much, much simpler with modern C++ language features (C++17):

```
for (const auto &[s, p] : A)
{
    const auto &[a, b] = p;

    std::cout << s << " " << a << " " << b << std::endl;
}
```

If your C++ textbook and/or compiler doesn't cover C++17, it is really worth one's time to update your documentation and/or your compiler to the current C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use range-based loop instead of iterators to avoid the problems with `*`:

```
for(const auto& itr:A)
{
    std::cout<< "Base Pair 1st: "<<itr.first<<" level pair 1st:"<<itr.second.first<<" level pair 2nd "<<itr.second.second;
}
```